# How to check if property exsist in array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an array with objects created dynamically. I'll use the next example:

```
const workers = [{
    Construction: 500,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    Debilite: 800,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    Marketing: 1200,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    'Human Resources': 1350,
    workers: 0
  },
]
```

How to find if the property name exists and change its value?
For example, if 'Construction' property exists, change its value from 500 to 800 and workers should change from 0 to 1.

Comment: When you say you want to change its value from 500 to 800, do you mean you want to only change the value if its existing value is 500? Or were you just phrasing it that way to fit your example?

Comment: Iterate the array, check every object. Problem = attempt = where?

Comment: if (workers[index].Construction !== undefined){ // do smth }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the object and assign the new values.

```js
function update(array, key, values) {
    Object.assign(array.find(o => key in o) || {}, values);
}

const workers = [{ Construction: 500, workers: 0 }, { Debilite: 800, workers: 0 }, { Marketing: 1200, workers: 0 }, { 'Human resources': 1350, workers: 0 }];

update(workers, 'Construction', { Construction: 800, workers: 1 });

console.log(workers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array, examine each object, update as needed.

You do have two syntax errors with your code:

1. There should not be a comma after the last item in an array.
2. `Human resources` is not a valid object key unless it's in quotes.

```js
const workers = [
  { Construction: 500, workers: 0 },
  { Debilite: 800, workers: 0 },
  { Marketing: 1200, workers: 0 },
  { "Human resources": 1350, workers: 0 } // <-- No comma after last array item and no spaces in key unless quoted
];

// Loop over the array
workers.forEach(function(obj){
  // Check current array item for existence of property
  if(obj.Construction){
    // Update as needed
    obj.Construction = 800;
    obj.workers = 1; 
  }
});

console.log(workers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `array` of `objects`.

So you need to follow two steps:

1. Loop through the `array` (either using a `for` loop, or using `forEach`)
2. On each iteration of the loop use `object.hasOwnProperty(key)`

In this case you can use something like:

```
workers.forEach((worker) => {

  if (worker.hasOwnProperty('Construction')) {
    worker['Construction'] = 800;
    worker['workers'] = 1;
  }
});
```

**Working Example:**

```js
const workers = [{
    Construction: 500,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    Debilite: 800,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    Marketing: 1200,
    workers: 0
  },
  {
    'Human Resources': 1350,
    workers: 0
  },
];

workers.forEach((worker) => {

  if (worker.hasOwnProperty('Construction')) {
    worker['Construction'] = 800;
    worker['workers'] = 1;
  }
});

console.log(workers);
```